# How normal is it to take a freelance job without interviewing first?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

For instance, a recruiter says their client wants someone to start the next week, and go for a few weeks, possibly to full-time. However, the client told the recruiter that they do not want to interview anyone - they want to evaluate the freelancer on the job.

Is this a normal practice for freelancer positions? It seems risky for the candidate to accept a job without even meeting anyone, reviewing a job description, or even going to the office first.

Comment: Let's say it's a lead role for an agency, on the design/product/strategy side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, regularly - for fixed/short term work

You probably wouldn't want to take a 2 year contract like that but you aren't accepting that: you're accepting a 3 week temporary freelance assignment with the possibility that they'll offer you a longer term assignment.

They presumably have seen your portfolio or similar, and you have some information about the project - that's usually enough for short term work where there's little to be lost for either party. If you're still unsure perhaps ask for some more detail or examples of what they already have in the works so you can gauge the state of play. Equally if they needed more examples of portfolio work they could ask.

So there's little risk, and the 3 weeks works much like an interview for the longer piece of work.

Comment: What if there's no interest in a longer piece of work, because the client is just not interesting? Or, if the only information about the type of project is what is on the client's website? What about the opportunity cost of taking on an unknown project, vs continuing to pursue something better and longer term? I guess 2-3 weeks won't hurt anyone, but I'm curious about your opinion on these other questions.

Comment: Then (in order) you don't accept the extension. You ask for more info or then it down depending on your own circumstances. And with opportunity costs again it's on your own circumstances, but I find it's rare that a start needs to be rushed through in 2-3 weeks, particularly if it isn't even on your radar right now

Answer (score 5):

Do they pay?

To me this is like the US Priority Mail - if it fits it ships.  I get my rate then I work.

From their perspective they could interview 5 candidates and use up a lot interview time to predict who will work.  Or just bring one on board and pay to see what they actually do.  And they want someone to start next week.

Comment: It's all down to pay.  Companies who get interviewees to work for free are a few hairs short from a scam.  If he puts you on payroll immediately, and accepts the risk of paying for someone useless, then go for it.  If they want you to carry all the risks to work for free, and ultimately gives you ZERO assurance for recourse (e.g. a contract), then don't bother.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. And it's a bit flippant.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/40504)

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager To me it does answer the question. I don't have any questions.  No I don't have statistics on how often this happens but I give clear reasons. I have been placed many times where I just go to the job.  It has up votes so some people seem to think it is even a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a normal practice for freelancer positions?

Not for inhouse jobs, normally at least a quick meeting if not an interview unless the person is a well know expert. I've had plenty of jobs without doing any real interview just because someone recommended me. In fact probably 90% of my work comes like that. But it's not normal to get a total stranger that way.

It's normal enough for relatively low level or even expert online work, because if they're not up to scratch you just don't pay them. And being a good 'fit' is less important.

Comment: In this case, the "recommendation" would be coming from a recruiter. I don't know if that fits your example of being recommended by someone or if that fits being a total stranger. What do you think?

Comment: A total stranger in my opinion...